# How to save a variable to a database in three.js

Tags: node.js, three.js, replit, replit-database

I have made a simple game in three.js and want to be able to save a high score to a database, but anytime I try to use a database module, more specifically, the replit database, all of the three.js code stops working.

I have tried to import the replit database module in the file, but it doesn't work, anytime I try and reference another file from the three.js script, all of it stops working.

this is how I have three.js imported

`import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";`

Comment: Are you mixing frontend and backend code perhaps?
Refactor your question and post a error message and specify your problem. Your post is to vague to give you a answer.